# Adding data sources for unixODBC/isql on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, unixodbc

I have installed unixODBC from source and [mysql-odbc connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) from .dmg installer on Mac OSX Lion. This was done a while ago, and at that time I successfully installed a data source (let's call it `foo`). Now I am trying to add another data source (DSN). I've done this through both [ODBC Manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) and the command-line tool myodbc-installer given with the tar bundle of the mysql-odbc connector from the mysql website. An entry shows up in `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`, which looks like this:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
bar = MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver

[ODBC]
Trace         = 0
TraceAutoStop = 0
TraceFile     = 
TraceLibrary  = 

[myodbc]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so
SERVER = localhost
PORT   = 3306

[bar]
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Description = 
DATABASE    = bar
```

However, isql fails to find it:

```
anitya:Preferences neil$ isql bar bar bar -v
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Weird thing is, the old DSN `foo`, which is not to be seen in /Library/ODBC/odbc.ini or /etc/odbc.ini, works fine:

```
anitya:Preferences neil$ isql foo foo foo
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

I'm miffed about where the DSN entries need to be entered on OSX Lion to be found by isql. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: OS X ships with [outdated](https://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10103/), but [updateable](http://www.iodbc.org/), iODBC driver manager, which uses the config files at `/Library/ODBC/odbc*.ini` and `/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc*.ini`.  It's usually easier to build your ODBC-compliant tools with iODBC and use these files, than to force unixODBC into OS X. Symlinks can be made from whatever specific location an app developer decided was special, to the default files.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the odbc file is in /usr/local/etc/